# Adding SQL constraint on attribtes of different tables

Tags: sql, database-design, spring-data-jpa, unique-constraint

I have tables

```
Question (int id,string question, int questionNumber)
Option (int id, string option, int optionNumber)
```

How can I constrain pair `(questionNumber, optionNumber)` to be unique?

How can I apply this through Spring data JPA?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: You can't create a constraint on columns in different tables and I don't think you need to that here either. You need to map the questions and the various options (answers) together either as one-to-many or many-to-many relationship. Either way, you will end up having question and option ids in one table, and there you can create a unique constraint on the two columns. Although I'm a bit lost as to what questionnumber and optionnumber columns stand for.

Answer (score 0):

You have business keys; a question number and option numbers. A question number must uniquely identify a question. And an option number must uniquely identify an option within a question.

This would be something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE question
(
  question_number  INT            NOT NULL,
  question         VARCHAR(1000)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (question_number)
);

CREATE TABLE option
(
  question_number  INT            NOT NULL,
  option_number    INT            NOT NULL,
  option           VARCHAR(1000)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (question_number, option_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (question_number) REFERENCES question(question_number)
);
```

You want to add technical IDs to your tables, though, and it seems you want to use them as primary keys. That makes this a little more complicated.

```
CREATE TABLE question
(
  id               INT            NOT NULL,
  question_number  INT            NOT NULL,
  question         VARCHAR(1000)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT uq_question UNIQUE (question_number)
);

CREATE TABLE option
(
  id               INT            NOT NULL,
  question_id      INT            NOT NULL,
  option_number    INT            NOT NULL,
  option           VARCHAR(1000)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question(id),
  CONSTRAINT uq_option UNIQUE (question_id, option_number)
);
```

With a database built on technical primary keys you want your IDs to be unique and your business keys, too. So you end up with more unique constraints in the database.